# Should include_headers be placed that way?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Hitting the Facebook graph api with a batched request:

```
curl -F 'access_token=mytoken' -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","relative_url":"me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,picture.width(100).height(100),email", "include_headers":"false"},
{ "method":"GET","relative_url":"me?fields=picture.type(large)", "include_headers":"false"}]'     https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2
```

The result **still contain the headers**.
I don't expect them in the result.

Is the `"include_headers":"false"` syntax wrong or misplaced?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to exclude the headers in batch requests a few different ways. I'm doing it from the PHP SDK but it's all the same under the covers.

1. By passing it as a POST parameter on the top-level request, i.e. add `-F "include_headers=false"` to your curl command
2. By passing it as a GET parameter on the inner request(s), not as a separate field, i.e. append `"&include_headers=false"` to relative_url

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the python facebook-sdk this does the trick:

```
rezs = self.graph.request("?include_headers=false",
                          post_args={"batch": batched_requests})
```

where my `self.graph` is:

```
self.graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=access_token,
                                   version="2.5")
```

and the `batched_requests` is a string containing the IDs and fields that I want.